# Deshabilitar un texbox para poder ingresar datos en otra c#

Tags: c#

Ok, estoy haciendo una calculadora, lo cual ya esta funcional, pero agregue una opción para que me re-dimensione el formulario, y me muestre un un conversor de temperatura, mi problema radica básicamente el el primer texbox (el que muestra los resultados en la calculadora) ya que cuando ingreso datos en el texbox del conversor para realizar la transformación el valor que ingreso también me aparece en el texbox de la calculadora, y yo no quiero que eso sea así, cabe mencionar que tengo la propiedad keypress activa en el formulario, para que me permita ingresar datos por teclado, pero cuando hago eso en mi otro texbox del conversor pasa eso, como puedo hacer para corregirlo? ya probé poniéndole la propiedad redonly, la de enabled en false, pero nada, también le cambie las etiquetas y el nombre del diseño, no quiero quitar el ingreso por teclado, ayúdenme please. Ahi esta todo mi código, esta comentado justo en la parte de mi problema, pueden revisarlo, les también una captura, por favor, ayúdenme, muchas gracias de antemano.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication16
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
            string op = " ";
        double resultado = 0;
        bool detectaoperacion = false;
        bool punto = true;
        bool labelmemory = false;
        double memoria;
        double signos;
        string borrado, point;
        float iCelsius, iFahrenheit, iKevin;
        char ioperation;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Width = 298;
            txtrespuesta.Width = 266;

        }

        private void Boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((txtrespuesta.Text == "0") || (detectaoperacion))
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "";
                detectaoperacion = false;
            }
            Button Botonesnu = (Button)sender;
                    txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + Botonesnu.Text;
        }

        private void Botones_Operaciones(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button botonesoperaciones = (Button)sender;
            op = botonesoperaciones.Text;
            resultado = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            txtrespuesta.Text = "";
            lblecuasiones.Text= System.Convert.ToString(resultado) + " " + op;
            btnigual.Focus();

        }

        private void btnigual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblecuasiones.Text = "";
            switch(op)
            {
                case "+":
                    txtrespuesta.Text = (resultado + Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    txtrespuesta.Text = (resultado - Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    txtrespuesta.Text = (resultado * Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    txtrespuesta.Text = (resultado / Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "√":
                    txtrespuesta.Text = Math.Sqrt(resultado).ToString();
                    break;
                case "X²":
                    txtrespuesta.Text = (resultado * resultado).ToString();
                    break;
                case "%":
                    txtrespuesta.Text= ((resultado * resultado) /100).ToString();
                    break;
                case "EXP":
                    double i = Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
                    double q;
                    q = (resultado);
                    txtrespuesta.Text = Math.Exp(i * Math.Log(q * 4)).ToString();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            lblecuasiones.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnce_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
            resultado = 0;


        }

        private void btnc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
            lblecuasiones.Text = "";
            resultado = 0;
        }

        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyChar.ToString())
            {
                case "0":
                    btn0.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    btn1.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    btn2.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    btn3.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "4":
                    btn4.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    btn5.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    btn6.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "7":
                    btn7.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "8":
                    btn8.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "9":
                    btn9.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "+":
                    btnmas.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    btnmenos.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    btndividir.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    btnmul.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "%":

                    break;
                case "r":
                    btnraiz.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "c":
                    cuadrado.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "p":
                    btnporcentaje.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case ".":
                    btnpunto.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "\b":
                    btnretroceso.PerformClick();
                    break;
                case "e":
                    btnce.PerformClick();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;


            }
         }

        //Botoncito pa' el punto
        private void btnpunto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (punto == true)
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = txtrespuesta.Text + ".";
                punto = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
            punto = true;
            if(punto == true)
            {
                resultado = resultado + .0;
                resultado.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

        }

        private void btnmc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = 0;
            labelmemory = false;
        }

        private void btnmr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = memoria.ToString();
        }

        private void btnms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = System.Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            labelmemory = true;
        }

        private void btnmmas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = memoria + System.Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            labelmemory = true;
        }

        private void btnmmenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memoria = memoria - System.Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            labelmemory = true;
        }

        private void estadisticasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }

        private void cientificaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Width = 482;
            txtrespuesta.Width = 447;


        }

        private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(txtrespuesta.Text);
        }

        private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = " "; //Limpiar pantalla primero
            txtrespuesta.Paste();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void aboutCalculatorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form3 = new Form3();
            Form3.Show();
        }

        private void vistaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void estandarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Width = 298;
            txtrespuesta.Width = 266;

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void programmerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Width = 800;

        }

        private void unitConvertertToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }

        private void btnmasmenos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            signos = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            signos = signos - (signos * 2);
            txtrespuesta.Text = signos.ToString();
        }

        private void BtnPi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Text = "3.14159265358979323";
        }

        private void Button_log_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double ilog = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("log" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            ilog = Math.Log10(ilog);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ilog);
        }

        private void Button_Asin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qSinh= double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Sinh" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            qSinh = Math.Sinh(qSinh);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(qSinh);
        }

        private void Button_sin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qSin = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Sin" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            qSin = Math.Sin(qSin);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(qSin);

        }

        private void Button_Cos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qCos = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Cos" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            qCos= Math.Cos(qCos);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(qCos);
        }

        private void btncosh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qCosh = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Cosh" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            qCosh = Math.Cosh(qCosh);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(qCosh);
        }

        private void Button_Tan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qTan = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Tan" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            qTan = Math.Tan(qTan);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(qTan);
        }

        private void btntanh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qTanh = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Tanh" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            qTanh = Math.Tanh(qTanh);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(qTanh);

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    txtrespuesta.Text = (resultado % Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text)).ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = int.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a);
        }

        private void btnbin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = int.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Binary" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a,2);
        }

        private void btnhex_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = int.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Hexadecimal" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a,16);
        }

        private void btnoct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = int.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Octal" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a,8);
        }

        private void x2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a;
            a = Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("sqr" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a);
        }

        private void x3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a;
            a = Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("cube" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a);
        }

        private void btnreciproco_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double a;
            a = Convert.ToDouble(1.0 / Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text));
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Reciprococ" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(a);
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ioperation = 'C';
        }

        private void rbfahrentocelc_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ioperation = 'F';
        }

        private void rbkevin_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ioperation = 'K';
        }
        // instruccion para calcular el resultado de la convercion en el boton calcular, con datos desde el texbox2
        private void btnconvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtrespuesta.Enabled = false;
            txtrespuesta.ReadOnly = true;
            switch (ioperation)
            {
                case 'C':
                    txtrespuesta.Enabled = false;
                    txtrespuesta.ReadOnly = true;
                    iCelsius = float.Parse(convert.Text);
                    lblconvert.Text = ((((9 * iCelsius) / 5) + 32).ToString());

                break;

                case 'F':
                    iFahrenheit = float.Parse(convert.Text);
                    lblconvert.Text = ((((iFahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9).ToString());
                    break;

                case 'K':
                    iKevin = float.Parse(convert.Text);
                    lblconvert.Text =(((((9 * iKevin) / 5) + 32) + 273.15).ToString());

                    break;

            }
        }

        private void btnreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            convert.Text = "";
            lblconvert.Text = "";
            rbcelctofahren.Checked = false;
            rbfahrentocelc.Checked = false;
            rbkevin.Checked = false;
        }

        private void diguitGroupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }

        private void dateCalculatorToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }

        private void moToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }

        private void fuelEconomiToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form5 = new Form5();
            Form5.Show();
        }

        private void viewHelpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form Form6 = new Form6();
            Form6.Show();

        }

        private void btnexp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double i = Convert.ToDouble(txtrespuesta.Text);
            double q;
            q = (resultado);
            double ilog = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Exp" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            txtrespuesta.Text = Math.Exp(i * Math.Log(q * 4)).ToString();
        }

        private void inx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double ilog = double.Parse(txtrespuesta.Text);
            lblecuasiones.Text = System.Convert.ToString("Logn" + "(" + (txtrespuesta.Text + ")"));
            ilog = Math.Log(ilog);
            txtrespuesta.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ilog);
        }

        private void Button_Xmenos1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnretroceso_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            borrado = txtrespuesta.Text;
            point = txtrespuesta.Text;
            x = borrado.Length - 1;
            y = point.Length - 1;
            point = point.Substring(y,1);
            borrado = borrado.Substring(0,x);
            txtrespuesta.Text = borrado;
            if (txtrespuesta.Text == "")
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
                detectaoperacion = true;
            }
            if (txtrespuesta.Text == "-")
            {
                txtrespuesta.Text = "0";
                detectaoperacion = true;
            }
            if (point == ".")
            {
                punto = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// instruccion para calcular el resultado de la convercion en el boton calcular, con datos desde el texbox2

```
    private void btnconvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtrespuesta.Enabled = false;
        txtrespuesta.ReadOnly = true;
        switch (ioperation)
        {
            case 'C':
                txtrespuesta.Enabled = false;
                txtrespuesta.ReadOnly = true;
                iCelsius = float.Parse(convert.Text);
                lblconvert.Text = ((((9 * iCelsius) / 5) + 32).ToString());

            break;

            case 'F':
                iFahrenheit = float.Parse(convert.Text);
                lblconvert.Text = ((((iFahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9).ToString());
                break;

            case 'K':
                iKevin = float.Parse(convert.Text);
                lblconvert.Text =(((((9 * iKevin) / 5) + 32) + 273.15).ToString());

                break;
```

Comment: Creo que no me ise entender bien, no tengo problemas con el resultado, de echo me los calculado bien, el problema esta al ingresar los datos, ya que ingreso algo por el texbox de el conversor, y automaticamente tambien el el otro de la calculadora

Comment: Mi error, yo no he leído bien.

Comment: trate de leer todo tu codigo.. no entiendo como puede ser que ponga el valor en los dos textbox. podes poner como se llaman los dos textbox, y donde esta el pedazo que descubriste tiene el problema? no lo encuentro por ningun lado.

Comment: Claro, yo igual haha el texbox de la calculadora se llama txtrespuesta, miestras que el de la conversion se llama txtconvert

Comment: y donde de todo ese codigo esta txtconvert?

Comment: Ya colge el codigo, puedes revisarlo

Comment: ahi dice lblconvert, no txtconvert. sigo sin entender

Comment: Bueno, es que el resultado no lo saco directamente en un otro texbox, si no en un label que esta en un texbox

Comment: osea, pero ese no es el problema, por que el resultado si que me lo despliega bien, lo que pasa es que para ingresar valores  en el texbox que se llama convert , tambien me saca en el texbox  txtrespuesta

Comment: como? como que un label que esta en un textbox? si esto es winforms, no tenes un label dentro de un textbox. A ver.. ordena la pregunta.. saca todo el codigo que no sea relevante. Depura! y si escribis en un textbox o en otro, es logico que escriba en los dos, deberias cancelar la entrada y hacerla manual.

Comment: Todo esta en orden, y si, yo agrege un label dentro de texbox, pero no tiene nada de malo no?, como sea, no quiero hacer la entrada manual y tener que presionar los numeros con el teclado

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está pasando es que en tu código estás gestionando el evento `KeyPress` global del Form, y en él rediriges todas las pulsaciones a `txtrespuesta`. Como lo que quieres es poder teclear en el `textbox2`, debes comprobar en el manejador del evento `KeyPress` si este tiene foco, para no enviar las pulsaciones de teclado al otro en ese caso. Algo asi:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(!textbox2.Focused)
    {
        //si el textbox2 no tiene el foco, mandamos las pulsaciones a la calculadora
        switch (e.KeyChar.ToString())
        {
             //aqui todo el código que tienes actuamente
             ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciono, y corriguio el error, pero haora, me lee todo el teclado, osea, haora los texbox's funcionan independientemente, pero me habilito todo el teclado, osea, me deja escribir leras, y esas cosas, y yo solo quiero que funcione con numeros, y algunas teclas del teclado que yo asigno?

Comment: @AxwellDuarte claro,ahora debes controlar el keypress del textbox2 y filtrar las teclas igual que haces en el Form1_KeyPress.

Comment: Bueno, ya funcionan independientemente, pero en los 2 texbox haora tengo ese problema de que todo el teclado este habilitado, no deberia de ser en uno solo?

Comment: Como lo filtro, quiero decir, al principio no tenia pensado que habian mas de un texbox, asi que le asigne un keypress al formulario entero, y luego a los botones virtuales les asigne un metodo de click para que cuando presione una tecla este simule un click

Comment: Pero, haora despues de hacer lo de arriba, parece ser que no tiene efecto ese metodo

Comment: Pero, haora despues de hacer lo de arriba, parece ser que no tiene efecto ese metodo

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que en tu función Form1_KeyPress, te coge la pulsación del teclado hecha en todo el formulario, por lo que también en el txtConvert (que es lo que quieres evitar si no me equivoco)

Deberías definir una función del tipo txtRespuesta_KeyPress, asignándola al evento de pulsación de tecla del txtRespuesta, por ejemplo

```
txtRespuesta.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtRespuesta_KeyPress);
```

Así sólo se ejecutará ese método cuando tengas el foco en txtRespuesta en vez de en todo el formulario

Comment: y exactamente, donde deberia de crear la funcion?

Comment: a la misma 'altura' que tu función actual, pero en vez de asignarla a la tecla pulsada en todo el formulario, la asignas a la tecla pulsada en el txtRespuesta